# How to create a custom Transformer from a UDF?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-ml

I was trying to create and save a [Pipeline](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline) with custom stages. I need to add a `column` to my `DataFrame` by using a `UDF`. Therefore, I was wondering if it was possible to convert a `UDF` or a similar action into a `Transformer`?

My custom `UDF` looks like this and I'd like to learn how to do it using an `UDF` as a custom `Transformer`.

```
def getFeatures(n: String) = {
    val NUMBER_FEATURES = 4  
    val name = n.split(" +")(0).toLowerCase
    ((1 to NUMBER_FEATURES)
         .filter(size => size <= name.length)
         .map(size => name.substring(name.length - size)))
} 

val tokenizeUDF = sqlContext.udf.register("tokenize", (name: String) => getFeatures(name))
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is not a fully featured solution but your can start with something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.{UnaryTransformer}
import org.apache.spark.ml.util.Identifiable
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{ArrayType, DataType, StringType}

class NGramTokenizer(override val uid: String)
  extends UnaryTransformer[String, Seq[String], NGramTokenizer]  {

  def this() = this(Identifiable.randomUID("ngramtokenizer"))

  override protected def createTransformFunc: String => Seq[String] = {
    getFeatures _
  }

  override protected def validateInputType(inputType: DataType): Unit = {
    require(inputType == StringType)
  }

  override protected def outputDataType: DataType = {
    new ArrayType(StringType, true)
  }
}
```

Quick check:

```
val df = Seq((1L, "abcdef"), (2L, "foobar")).toDF("k", "v")
val transformer = new NGramTokenizer().setInputCol("v").setOutputCol("vs")

transformer.transform(df).show
// +---+------+------------------+
// |  k|     v|                vs|
// +---+------+------------------+
// |  1|abcdef|[f, ef, def, cdef]|
// |  2|foobar|[r, ar, bar, obar]|
// +---+------+------------------+
```

You can even try to generalize it to something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection.schemaFor
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

class UnaryUDFTransformer[T : TypeTag, U : TypeTag](
  override val uid: String,
  f: T => U
) extends UnaryTransformer[T, U, UnaryUDFTransformer[T, U]]  {

  override protected def createTransformFunc: T => U = f

  override protected def validateInputType(inputType: DataType): Unit = 
    require(inputType == schemaFor[T].dataType)

  override protected def outputDataType: DataType = schemaFor[U].dataType
}

val transformer = new UnaryUDFTransformer("featurize", getFeatures)
  .setInputCol("v")
  .setOutputCol("vs")
```

If you want to use UDF not the wrapped function you'll have to extend `Transformer` directly and override `transform` method. Unfortunately majority of the useful classes is private so it can be rather tricky.

Alternatively you can register UDF:

```
spark.udf.register("getFeatures", getFeatures _)
```

and use `SQLTransformer`

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.SQLTransformer

val transformer = new SQLTransformer()
  .setStatement("SELECT *, getFeatures(v) AS vs FROM __THIS__")

transformer.transform(df).show
// +---+------+------------------+
// |  k|     v|                vs|
// +---+------+------------------+
// |  1|abcdef|[f, ef, def, cdef]|
// |  2|foobar|[r, ar, bar, obar]|
// +---+------+------------------+
```

Comment: I tried to save my model but it says `Message: Pipeline write will fail on this Pipeline because it contains a stage which does not implement Writable. Non-Writable stage: ngramtokenizer_f784079e2124 of type class` do i have to implement the Writable interface?

Comment: This the bad part I've mentioned before. As far as I know the best approach is to implement `DefaultParamsWritable` and `DefaultParamsReadable` but it won't be possible without putting at least a part of your code in ML package. You can try with `MLWritable` / `MLReadable`  though.

Answer (score 1):

I initially tried to extend the `Transformer` and `UnaryTransformer` abstracts but encountered trouble with my application being unable to reach `DefaultParamsWriteable`.As an example that may be relevant to your problem, I created a simple term normalizer as a UDF following along from [this example](http://www.sparktutorials.net/using-sparksql-udfs-to-create-date-times-in-spark-1.5). My goal is to match terms against patterns and sets to replace them with generic terms. For example:

```
"\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b".r -> "emailaddr"
```

This is the class

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex

class TermNormalizer(normMap: Map[Any, String]) {
  val normalizationMap = normMap

  def normalizeTerms(terms: Seq[String]): Seq[String] = {
    var termsUpdated = terms
    for ((term, idx) <- termsUpdated.view.zipWithIndex) {
      for (normalizer <- normalizationMap.keys: Iterable[Any]) {
        normalizer match {
          case (regex: Regex) =>
            if (!regex.findFirstIn(term).isEmpty) termsUpdated = 
              termsUpdated.updated(idx, normalizationMap(regex))
          case (set: Set[String]) =>
            if (set.contains(term)) termsUpdated = 
              termsUpdated.updated(idx, normalizationMap(set))
        }
      }
    }
    termsUpdated
  }
}
```

I use it like this:

```
val testMap: Map[Any, String] = Map("hadoop".r -> "elephant",
  "spark".r -> "sparky", "cool".r -> "neat", 
  Set("123", "456") -> "set1",
  Set("789", "10") -> "set2")

val testTermNormalizer = new TermNormalizer(testMap)
val termNormalizerUdf = udf(testTermNormalizer.normalizeTerms(_: Seq[String]))

val trainingTest = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (0L, "spark is cool 123", 1.0),
  (1L, "adsjkfadfk akjdsfhad 456", 0.0),
  (2L, "spark rocks my socks 789 10", 1.0),
  (3L, "hadoop is cool 10", 0.0)
)).toDF("id", "text", "label")

val testTokenizer = new Tokenizer()
  .setInputCol("text")
  .setOutputCol("words")

val tokenizedTrainingTest = testTokenizer.transform(trainingTest)
println(tokenizedTrainingTest
  .select($"id", $"text", $"words", termNormalizerUdf($"words"), $"label").show(false))
```

Now that I read the question a little closer, it sounds like you're asking how to avoid doing it this way lol. Anyways, I'll still post it in case someone in the future is looking for an easy way to apply a transformer-ish like functionality

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to make the transformer writable as well, then you can re-implement the traits such as HasInputCol in the sharedParams library in a public package of your choice and then use them with DefaultParamsWritable trait to make the transformer persistable.

This way you can also avoid having to place part of your code inside the spark core ml packages but you kind of maintain a parallel set of params in your own package. This isnt really a problem given they hardly ever change.

But do track the bug in their JIRA board [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7146) that asks for some of the common sharedParams to be made public instead of private to the ml so that people can directly use those from outside classes.