# Spark VectorAssembler transformer with Strings

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

First, let's define a couple of Spark dataframes `dfString` and `dfDouble` respectively made up of `strings` and `doubles` as such:

```
val dfString = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(("a1", "b1", "c1"), ("a2", "b2", "c2"))).toDF("colx", "coly", "colz")
val dfDouble = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq((0.0, 1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.0, 5.0))).toDF("colx", "coly", "colz")
```

Second, we prepare a pipeline made up of a single transformer:

```
val va = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("colx", "coly", "colz")).setOutputCol("ft")
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(va))
```

Fitting this pipeline to `dfDouble` will return the expected result where all columns are concatenated into a single column called `ft`. But `pipeline.fit(dfString)` throws

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data type StringType is not
>   supported.

The question is: How to obtain the same result with the strings as we get from the doubles while keeping within the pipeline framework?

Note that this is not a duplicate of [Concatenate columns in apache spark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31450846/concatenate-columns-in-apache-spark-dataframe) since

- I want to use only transformers to go in a pipeline framework
- and that I do not want to use a
  `StringIndexer` transformer.

I am using Spark 1.6.

Comment: _How to obtain the same result_ - it is not possible since `Vector` type cannot store strings. If you want to build an array you'll have to write your own transformer.

Comment: I'm surprised since it feels like something quite natural to want to do.  Could you please give a hint about how to get started?

Comment: Not so much. There is not easy to find a scenario in ML where it can be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35180527/how-to-create-a-custom-transformer-from-a-udf